# Pass objects to shiny app and launch with runApp

Tags: r, scope, shiny

I am creating a package that contains a few interactive shiny apps. The purpose of these apps is to facilitate GUI exploration of in-memory objects. For example, I have an object consisting of discretized variables I would like to pass to the shiny app and then make adjustments via the GUI interface.

However, I am running into trouble when trying to access this in-memory object from the Shiny App.

Here is the relevant code:

First, I am wrapping the `shinyServer` function in another function. My thought here is to give the shiny server access to the passed object.

```
    #' @export
    appServer <- function(bins) {
      su <- summary(bins)
      shinyServer(function(input, output) {

        ## values that should trigger updates when changed
        values <- reactiveValues(summary=su, i=1, bins=bins)

    # excluded rest of body for brevity ...

    }
```

In this function, I create a `shinyApp` object and pass in the ui (in another file) and the result of the `appServer` function defined above.

```
makeApp <- function(bins) {
  shiny::shinyApp(
    ui = appUI,
    server = appServer(bins))
}
```

The preceding functions are called in this function that wraps the call to `runApp` and takes an argument from the user.

```
#' @export
adjust <- function(bins) {
  ## access data from the app?

  app <- makeApp(bins)
  shiny::runApp(app)
}
```

**How can I pass an in-memory object to a shinyApp that is imported from another package?**

When I execute the above code, I receive the following error:

> ERROR:   path[1]="C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWMpvHT\widgetbinding23e8333e5298": The system cannot find the path specified

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/WAwn7y9ZEO8

Answer (score 5):

In the example below I demonstrate how you can pass an object `x` from the global environment or from any other environment to the shiny app and change its value. I'm not sure if this answers your question. It maybe prove useful anyway :)

```
library(shiny)

x <- 5
x
deparse(substitute(x)) # is going to do the trick

fun <- function(obj) {

  # get the name of the passed object
  object_to_change <- deparse(substitute(obj)) 

  # get the object from a given environment
  val <- get(object_to_change, envir = .GlobalEnv) 
  # ?environment

  # Save the object as a reactive value
  values <- reactiveValues(x = val)                                   

  # Now define the app that is going to change the value of x
  ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    br(),
    actionButton("quit", "Apply changes and quit"),
    textInput("new", "", value = NULL, placeholder = "Set new value of x"),
    textOutput("out")
  ))

  server <- function(input, output) {

    output$out <- renderPrint({ 
      values$x        
    })

    # change the value of x
    observe({
      req(input$new)
      values$x <- as.numeric(input$new)
    })

    # Apply changes and quit     
    observe({
      if (input$quit == 1) {
        assign(x = object_to_change, value = values$x, envir = .GlobalEnv)
        stopApp()
      } 
    })
  }
  # Run the app  
  shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
}

fun(x)

# Check the new value of x in the .GlobalEnv
x
```